# How do I specify particular points for discretization in Pyomo?

Tags: python, optimization, pyomo

I have a continuous-time Pyomo model of the form:

```
from pyomo.environ import *
from pyomo.dae import *

m      = ConcreteModel()
m.t    = ContinuousSet(bounds=(0,150)) 
m.T    = Param(default=150)
m.S    = Var(m.t, bounds=(0,None))
m.Sdot = DerivativeVar(m.S)

discretizer = TransformationFactory('dae.collocation')
discretizer.apply_to(m,nfe=100,ncp=3,scheme='LAGRANGE-RADAU')

m.obj  = Objective(expr=m.S[122],sense=maximize)
```

But, when I run the above code, I get the following error:

```
KeyError: "Error accessing indexed component: Index '120' is not valid for array component 'S'"
```

Looking at `list(m.t)`, I see that, sure enough, 122 is not included as a discretization point:

```
..., 121.73257700000001, 122.467423, ...
```

How can I specify points to be included in the discretization?

Answer (score 1):

You can force the discretizer to include specific points by adding them to the `ContinuousSet` *before* discretizing the model (see the online [documentation](https://software.sandia.gov/downloads/pub/pyomo/PyomoOnlineDocs.html#_dae_modeling_components)).  The easiest way for your particular case is probably to include the points in an initialization list:

```
m.t = ContinuousSet(bounds=(0,150), intialize=[122])
print list(m.t)
# [0, 122, 150]

m.S    = Var(m.t, bounds=(0,None))
m.Sdot = DerivativeVar(m.S)
discretizer = TransformationFactory('dae.collocation')
discretizer.apply_to(m,nfe=100,ncp=3,scheme='LAGRANGE-RADAU')
print list(m.t)
# ..., 121.323184, 122, 122.271339, ...
```